# create things api using http in AWS-IoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, iot, aws-iot

I am new to this AWS IoT. I am having a problem with creating things. For this, I have gone through this document:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_CreateThing.html

I am having a problem with authorization. I am getting this error:

> Failed to open TCP connection to xxxxxx.iot.us-east.amazonaws.com:443
>   (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

Comment: In the same document follow the authorization docs Here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorization.html

Comment: I am not being able to figure out how to authenticate

Comment: Are you trying to create thing using AWS_console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created thing on AWS IoT by:

```
class AwsIotService

  def self.create_thing(thing_name)
    begin
      iot = Aws::IoT::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
                             access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                             secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
      iot.create_thing(thing_name: thing_name)
    rescue Aws::IoT::Errors::ServiceError
    end
  end
end
```